# What is this syntax in ES6 or ES7?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I came across this syntax which I believe is ES6 or ES7. What do these lines of code do?

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It is neither, it's syntax that is going to be introduced in this year's release, ES2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exports an asynchronous [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which takes in an argument `taskData`. The asynchronous function is new syntax that is set to come with this year's release, ES2017, called the [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), though the rest of the code is ES6 (ES2015) and ES5 (ES2011). It goes hand-in-hand with [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

It's primarily useful to clean up promise chains, where the code can get really messy. Consider this example using promises, found [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/):

```
function loadStory() {
  return getJSON('story.json').then(function(story) {
    addHtmlToPage(story.heading);

    return story.chapterURLs.map(getJSON)
      .reduce(function(chain, chapterPromise) {
        return chain.then(function() {
          return chapterPromise;
        }).then(function(chapter) {
          addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
        });
      }, Promise.resolve());
  }).then(function() {
    addTextToPage("All done");
  }).catch(function(err) {
    addTextToPage("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
  }).then(function() {
    document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

The example above fetches a story, and iterates through all the chapters and adds them to the HTML. It works, but it can be very messy and hard to follow if you've got lots of stuff to do. Instead, you can use `async` and `await`, which is just syntactic sugar, but makes it much more clean:

```
async function loadStory() {
  try {
    let story = await getJSON('story.json');
    addHtmlToPage(story.heading);
    for (let chapter of story.chapterURLs.map(getJSON)) {
      addHtmlToPage((await chapter).html);
    }
    addTextToPage("All done");
  } catch (err) {
    addTextToPage("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
  }
  document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The above is (in my opinion) *way* more clean and easy to follow, versus the messy promise chain in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

This is an async function which is set to return Promise as @Andrew says.
It is using [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.

```
()=>{}
```

This function is in ES6 and does not define its own `this` context and any use of `this` will refer to the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

`Async await` syntax is set to be supported when ES2017 is released. Your code is essentially a function that returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Additionally, the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword allows for [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) when working with promises by use of the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword.

The `=>` part is called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which again is a syntactic sugar for the most part. It is part of ES6.

**Your function**

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

*... is almost the same as:*

```
module.exports = function(taskData) {
  return new Promise(function() {

    // do stuff
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(your return value)
  }
}
```

**Note:** the main difference is just the binding of the `this` keyword via the arrow function.

Comment: ES7 was released last year. You mean ES2017.